# Magento 2.3: How to configure fields to be used in Elasticsearch?

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I need to configure the list of fields that are searched when you search in Magento. I am using Elasticsearch 7 as the engine. I need to stop it from searching by SKU and manufacturer, and add in a custom attribute to search by - either by changing what is indexed or changing what fields are searched.

I'm digging through all of the module-elasticsearch code, but it's hard to find what I would need to override.

Answer (score 0):

I was digging way too deep. You can set whether or not an attribute is searchable in the Admin > Attributes > Product admin section. I was able to turn off search for manufacturer and sku, no problem.